# Why exactly does molten NaCl explode, when it is poured into water?

Tags: physical-chemistry, water, ionic-compounds, explosives

Why does molten $\ce{NaCl}$ explode, when it is poured into water?

$\ce{NaCl}$ has a high melting point, $1074\ \mathrm{K}$ ($801~\mathrm{^\circ C}$). $\ce{NaCl}$ has a molar mass of $58.44\ \mathrm{g/mol}$, it has specific heat capacity of $36.79\ \mathrm{J/(K\cdot mol)} = 629.53\ \mathrm{J/(K \cdot kg)}$. therefore the $\ce{NaCl}$ at melting point temperature has $491,033\ \mathrm{kJ/kg}$ more thermal energy than $\ce{NaCl}$ in STP conditions ($1\ \mathrm{atm}, 20~\mathrm{^\circ C}$, temperature difference $= 780\ \mathrm{K}$)

According to one [amateur video in youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDRWQUUUCF0), the molten salt explodes when it is poured into water (c. 2:15)

What is the exact cause of the explosion?

The author of the video reasons that the phenomenon is purely physical and it is caused by that water heats up, vaporises and expands as a gas inside the glimp of very hot $\ce{NaCl}$ salt. But is it really everything that happens there?

Other possible processes present in such occasion are (this is just a list what comes into my mind):

- rapid crystallisation of the $\ce{NaCl}$
- chemical reaction between $\ce{Na}$ and water: $$\ce{2 Na (s) + 2 H2O (l) -> 2 NaOH (aq) + H2 (g)}$$ (this causes explosion if $\ce{Na}$ is inserted into $\ce{H2O}$)
- reaction between $\ce{Cl}$ and water: $$\ce{Cl2 + H2O -> HOCl + HCl}$$
- the rapid solubility of hot $\ce{NaCl}$ into water
- thermal decomposition (thermolysis) of $\ce{H2O}$ into either monoatomic or diatomic hydrogen and oxygen, and reactions that follow this.

Also, the author fails to explain why no explosion occurs with sodium tetraborate nor sodium carbonate when each of them, in molten state, was poured into the water.

Comment: The author is completely right, and all other processes you mention are either totally negligible or downright impossible.

Comment: Also, Water is not $\ce{H20}$, but $\ce{H2O}$ (‘H twenty’ versus ‘H two Oh’).

Comment: @IvanNeretin That comment is not very helpful. Cool that you know the answer, but it doesn't really help OP.

The most interesting part is why this doesn't occur for sodium tetraborate and sodium carbonate. Perhaps this is why OP is sceptical of the explanation given by the author.

Comment: @Brian You comment sounds quite puzzling to me, as OP never said a thing about sodium tetraborate or sodium carbonate.

Comment: @Brian I’ll agree with Ivan that that was not part of the question asked or I would have had a more difficult time answering it.

Comment: Sodium Chloride hydrolise at high temperatures,btw

Comment: @IvanNeretin I only meant to say that it would be nice if you took the time to explain why the author is right, and why all of OP's suggestions are negligible or impossible. :-) That's what I was talking about when I mentioned "it doesn't really help OP". I tried to put a line break afterwards, but they get removed. The latter part was to bring to people's attention that different behavior is observed for sodium tetraborate and sodium carbonate (as it was shown in the linked video). If you believe this simple explanation for NaCl, wouldn't you expect the same for the other two?

Comment: @Jan He is asking if the author has the correct explanation. He links the experimental basis for the discussion, although he doesn't specifically bring up the discrepant behavior of sodium tetraborate and sodium carbonate... That's why I did... Because the authors explanation sounds very plausible, but since it doesn't occur for sodium tetraborate and sodium carbonate, we're missing part of the explanation. Which is what we're after, right :-)?

Comment: @Brian I'll modify the question to ask about why the same behavior is not observed with sodium tetraborate and sodium carbonate.

Comment: Now that makes the question quite different and a lot harder.

Comment: I’m not sure I approve of the moving question after it has been answered. I think I would prefer a second question asking for the interesting observation with borate and carbonate. CC @Brian. $$%$$Oh yeah. Protip for Chem.SE: `$$%$$` will fit in a display maths block which includes vertical space ;) Doesn’t work on SEs that don’t have MathJax.

Comment: I am fairly certain the author has never had his hands on molten sodium carbonate; it decomposes.

Answer (score 15):

Understand that sodium chloride is **not** made up of sodium metal and chlorine gas but of sodium *ions* and chloride *ions*, held together by ionic interactions. Under these thermal conditions (liquefication), the compound will not decompose into its elements and therefore all reactions you suggested which include elemental chlorine or sodium cannot occur.

Dissolution of sodium chloride in water is neither strongly exothermic nor strongly endothermic, so any effects stemming from the dissolution are neglegible.

Also note that you neglected an important variable in your calculations. As far as I can tell, you only calculate how to arrive at melting-point hot *solid* sodium chloride. To liquefy, additional melting enthalpy has to be applied, a further reservoir of energy to draw from. This melting enthalpy is of course released upon rapid crystallisation, but you should really subsume it into the heat energy difference altogether.

Finally, thermal decomposition of water is not exactly a process that will happen quickly, as exemplified by (water) steam temperatures that can be huge. Check out [this unrelated answer of mine](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/37665) about how much energy is required to heat water to $100~\mathrm{^\circ C}$ and boil it.

So all things considered: The principle contribution to the explosion is the rapid heating of water including boiling, leading to tightly compressed gaseous $\ce{H2O}$ which expands explosively. This concurs with the recrystallisation of $\ce{NaCl}$ which accounts for a non-neglegible portion of the energy added, but which is technically already present in molten $\ce{NaCl}$. All other processes are minor or impossible.

Comment: Yes. Your answer makes sense. But when the experimenter tried with another salt the same didn't happen. What is unique about NaCl for this to happen?

Comment: @shre_sudh_97 That is a different question that you didn’t ask.

Comment: The question has been modified to include this question as well.

Comment: Also really interested why it does not work with other types of salt

Answer (score 6):

$\ce{NaCl}$:

- Molar mass: $58.44~\mathrm{g~mol^{−1}}$
- Melting point: $801\mathrm{°C}$
- Specific heat capacity: $36.79~\mathrm{J~K^{-1}~mol^{−1}}$
- Std enthalpy change of fusion: $27.95~\mathrm{kJ~mol^{−1}}$

The energy required to melt $58~\mathrm{g}$ $\ce{NaCl}$ ($20\mathrm{°C} - 801\mathrm{°C}$) is roughly $56.6~\mathrm{kJ}$.

$\ce{H2O}$:

- Molar mass: $18.02~\mathrm{g~mol^{−1}}$
- Specific heat capacity: $75.375~\mathrm{J~K^{-1}~mol^{−1}}$
- Heat of vaporization: $40.657~\mathrm{kJ~mol^{−1}}$

The energy required to vaporize $18~\mathrm{g}$ $\ce{H2O}$ ($20\mathrm{°C} - 100\mathrm{°C}$) is roughly $46.7~\mathrm{kJ}$.

So $58~\mathrm{g}$ $\ce{NaCl}$ of $801\mathrm{°C}$ could vaporize $21.8~\mathrm{g}$ water of $20\mathrm{°C}$ giving roughly $27$ liters of vapor. This suffices to make some kind of explosion. However, if a explosion really occurs depends also on how fast the heat is transferred from the molten salt to water. A high viscosity of the molten salt e.g. will prevent fast heat transfer.

Comment: Nice quantitive answer. As you say its a sort of explosion, a physical one due to pressure not due to chemical reaction. Incidentally  I don't see why a viscous solid will prevent heat transfer since  there has to be  lots of interaction between molecules; if anything would have thought that the opposite would be true.

Comment: When the molten salt has low viscosity it is more likely to form smaller parts (drops) when poured into water. The greater surface would then enable a faster heat transfer and thus a more vigorous reaction. A liquid with high viscosity, such as a molten glass,  has less tnendeny to do so. This can be seen in the video where the borate retains the shape of a single drop that slowly cools down from the surface to the middle.

Answer (score 4):

Having looked at the video, it is clear that in the last experiment a small region of water around the very hot molten NaCl boule is turned to steam that rapidly expands and the shockwave causes the fish tank to explode. This must occur as there was sufficient energy left in the molten salt to completely vaporise a layer water next to it even though thermal diffusion (thermal conduction) in the water is carrying heat away and any bubbles of steam will try to rise out of the water. The steam produced is probably also super heated by the > 800 C molten salt and will continue to expand after the water boils. The reason that the cooler but still liquid salt did not vaporise enough water to crack the tank is probably that thermal conduction cools the melt and also removes heat from the water surrounding the boule and this wins out over heating enough of the water to vaporisation do do any damage.  Incidentally the  molten salt is probably molecular in nature; there is no water in the melt to make ions. Molecular NaCl (as a diatomic molecule) is well known in the vapour phase and its spectroscopy has been well studied as has NaI the iodine equivalent.

Comment: Yes, I think you nailed it. What I saw: As the molten salt entered the water, it was sheathed by a bed of superheated steam that keeps water away. Perhaps because of splashing, a small amount of superheated steam near the surface exploded. This caused a) a venting of the steam near the surface upwards and b) a sudden unsheathing of the molten salt from its steam bed as the surface shock propagated downwards and disrupted the hitherto organized molten salt flow. Once it became turbulent, vastly more energy transferred to the water, water instantaneously superheated and an explosion resulted.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect rather strongly that this is a **coulombic explosion**.

This phenomenon was only [recently described](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LmlAYnFF_s8) to explain the violent explosion of alkali metals in water. The explosion of alkali metals in water share some properties with molten salt explosions, specifically:

- it is extremely fast and violent - much faster than expected
- a similar set of alternate explanations (steam pressure, hydrogen combustion) have been attempted but have not been shown to work

Since molten salt is also conductive, a similar thing could be happening here.

One important observation that supports this is that the molten salt explosion only occurs when the salt is heated above a certain temperature. It is not enough for the salt to be simply molten. If the salt is below this temperature, there is almost no reaction (apart from steam). But when above this temperature, there is a completely different and explosive reaction. This can readily be seen in the different attempts in the OP's video. The third attempt (in which he made the salt 'really hot') is the only one that explodes.

An explosion will occur if the repulsion forces of the built-up charge within the salt exceeds the surface tension of the liquid salt. And it seems likely to me that both the electron affinity of the salt and its surface tension depend on temperature. If the force is below the surface tension, the salt will hold together while eventually cooling. If the force is above the surface tension, the salt will explode. This is consistent with observation.

This also provides a potential explanation for why the same explosion does not occur for sodium tetraborate or sodium carbonate. The electron affinity and surface tension are both likely to be different from those of NaCl.

The key to achieving an explosive effect is to bring out the energy within the salt (not just the energy at its surface). A coulombic explosion explains this because it predicts that the salt itself blasts apart, instantly exposing every internal portion in a violent chain reaction. This makes that internal thermal energy available almost instantly.